# Need help pulling duplicate names into a separate location without using conditional formatting

Tags: excel, macos

I need help pulling duplicates in excel and pulling information into another cell to identify reporting lines without conditional formatting. example Draco and Snape are taking the same class but I need to pull this information into  separate columns. See Below in my makeshift columns. Idk if it's relevant but information in columns A & B are unconstrained data being pulled in from a report.

Purpose of sheet: Class roster anyone at the company can take this class. Need to pull Direct reporting lines i.e. if Snap and Draco are taking the same class I need to highlight this information so they don't sit at the same table in the class OR are in the same Zoom breakout session.

First time posting and I'm bad with Excel lingo[Link to Google Sheet HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_TOavMxxtuUIL5NaEAuTjV4BTcii9N8leNlZAjNCU50/edit?usp=sharing)

|  | Worker Column A | Manager Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | Harry Potter | mcgonagall |  | Draco Malfoy | Severus Snape |
| 9 | Ronald Weasley | mcgonagall |  |  |  |
| 10 | Hermione Granger | mcgonagall |  |  |  |
| 11 | Severus Snape | Dumbledore |  |  |  |
| 12 | Draco Malfoy | Severus Snape |  |  |  |

Comment: Perhaps clarify your data to show what you have and what you want. Sharing on GoogleSheets works especially well, even if working with Excel.

Comment: How are they taking the same class? Because they're in the same row? It's not quite clear so far. Can you please clarify and add more example(s)?  What have you tried? (And FYI, the text like you posted is much better than a picture, so thanks. This way we can more easily copy/paste in to Excel and try ourselves).

Comment: Yeah I don't get the relationship either.

Comment: Cute that it's harry potter, but we need more information in order to understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Sorry everyone it's for work trying to not share information - I'm working on a class roster that you can take with your manager but in the class with breakout sessions we are trying to separate the Direct Report.  I'm trying to highlight these instances. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_TOavMxxtuUIL5NaEAuTjV4BTcii9N8leNlZAjNCU50/edit?usp=sharing

I would use conditional formatting but I'm using Workday Worksheets and they don't have conditional formatting available at this time so trying to find a workaround

Comment: @AmusinglySherm thanks for the clarification. I was under the impression it was actually for hogwartz.

Comment: you know I have an in at the school, so if you want to go just let me know :)